# Google Sign-in not working, instead redirects to Google homepage?

Tags: ios, xcode, google-signin

So I'm using Google sign-in on my app. When I sign in with Google, a page pops up and prompts me to sign in. When I do, instead of continuing to the rest of the app, the page stays and redirects me to the Google search homepage, leaving there no way to continue to the application. This problem is present when I'm using iOS 10, but not iOS 11. What is the issue here?

[image: The screen after signing in with Google]

Answer (score 0):

Please add this to your AppDelegate. For some reason this is needed to handle the redirection properly in iOS 10.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    if url.absoluteString.hasPrefix("com.googleusercontent.apps") {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                 sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                 annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
    }

    return true
}
```